# Deployment started failing - decryption operation failed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Deployment task of a pipeline has been working fine until yesterday.  No changes that Im aware of.  This is for a build that uses a deployment agent on an on-prem target.  Not sure where to look, other than possibly reinstall the build agent via the script?

```
2021-08-11T18:36:20.7233450Z ##[warning]Failed to download task 'DownloadBuildArtifacts'. Error The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.
2021-08-11T18:36:20.7243097Z ##[warning]Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException.Message}
2021-08-11T18:36:20.7247393Z ##[warning]Back off 28.375 seconds before retry.
2021-08-11T18:36:51.6834124Z ##[error]The decryption operation failed, see inner exception.
```

Answer (score 1):

Plese check announcement [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-190-update#changes-to-publishbuildartifacts-and-downloadbuildartifacts-tasks)

> The updated implementation of BuildArtifact tasks requires an agent upgrade, which should happen automatically unless automatic upgrades have been specifically disabled or the firewalls are incorrectly configured.
>
> If your agents are running in firewalled environments that did not follow the linked instructions, they may see failures when updating the agent or in the PublishBuildArtifacts or DownloadBuildArtifacts tasks until the firewall configuration is corrected.
>
> A common symptom of this problem are sudden errors relating to ssl handshakes or artifact download failures, generally on deployment pools targeted by Release Management definitions. Alternatively, if agent upgrades have been blocked, you might observe that releases are waiting for an agent in the pool that never arrives, or that agents go offline half-way through their update (this latter is related to environments that erroneously block the agent CDN).

To fix that, please update your self hosted agents.

Comment: I updated my agent to the latest 2.19 and I still get this error.  Not sure where this task is being used.

Comment: Can you enable System.Debuh to see if there are more meaningful messages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug

Comment: I enabled that checkbox when queing a new build, but no additional info was seen in the release stage that is failing.  Additionally, when I click on the stage, I used to be able to  see the logs, but now I have to navigate in and out of this several times before the logs will be displayed.  This happens in both Chrome and Edge

Comment: I think next Im going to manually remove and replace my on-prem agent via the powershell script

Comment: Well, phooey!  I manually replaced the agent, after removing the existing one, cleaning out the files and deleting the service.  When I got the new one installed and configured, I verified it was running and ran another build.  Exact same issue - encryption related error as listed above.  Arrgh

Comment: Just experienced the same issue @bitshift for approximately three days. Then, it just went away. Similarly, the issue appeared only on on-prem agents that had been running just fine for a long time.